# JqGrid - SubGrid not display data

Tags: c#, jquery, json, model-view-controller, jqgrid

After i try every thing from stackoverflow, i run out of ideas.
The problem is: i have jqGrid with one subgrid. The grid workly perfect, but subgrid not display data.

JS code:

```html
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#tblJQGrid").jqGrid(
    {
        url: '@Url.Action("GetDataForGrid", "Validator")',
        datatype: "json",
        mtype: 'GET',
        colNames: ['Archive Name', 'Upload By', 'Upload Date', 'Size in Mb'],
        colModel: [
        { name: 'ArchiveName', index: 'ArchiveName', width: 150, stype: 'text' },
        { name: 'UploadUser', index: 'UploadUser', width: 150 },
        { name: 'UploadDate', index: 'UploadDate', width: 150 },
        { name: 'Size', index: 'Size', width: 150 }
        ],
        sortname: 'ArchiveName',
        rowNum: 10,
        autowidth: true,
        height: "auto",
        gridview: true,
        emptyrecords:"No records...",
        loadonce: true,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30],
        pager: '#jQGridDemoPager',
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: 'desc',
        caption: "List Pending Archive",
        scrollOffset: 0,
        subGrid: true,
        subGridOptions:{ 
            plusicon : "ui-icon-plus",
            minusicon : "ui-icon-minus",
            openicon: "ui-icon-carat-1-sw", 
            expandOnLoad: false, 
            selectOnExpand : false, 
            reloadOnExpand : true 
        },

        subGridRowExpanded: function (subgrid_id, row_id) {
            var subgrid_table_id;
            var pager_id;
            var d = [{ "Id": 0, "FileName": "91606246.pdf", "Size": 0.03 }];
            subgrid_table_id = subgrid_id + "_t";
            pager_id = "p_" + subgrid_table_id;
            var cellValue = $("#tblJQGrid").jqGrid('getCell', row_id, 'ArchiveName');
            //jQuery("#" + subgrid_id).html("<table id='" + subgrid_table_id + "' class='scroll'></table><div id='" + pager_id + "' class='scroll'></div>");
            jQuery("#" + subgrid_id).html("<table id='" + subgrid_table_id + "' class='scroll'></table>");
            jQuery("#" + subgrid_table_id).jqGrid({
                jsonReader: {
                    repeatitems: false,
                    cell: "",
                    id: "0"
                },
                url: '@Url.Action("GetDataSubGrid", "Validator")?FileName=' + cellValue,
              
                //mtype: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                colNames: ['Id', 'Archive Name', 'Size in Mb'],
                colModel: [
                  { name: "Id", index: "Id", width: 20, sortable: true },
                  { name: "FileName", index: "FileName", width: 130,sortable:true },
                  { name: "Size", index: "Size", width: 80, align: "right" },
                ],
                height: 'auto',
                //loadonce: true,
                //gridview: true,
                //autoencode: true,
                rowNum: 20,
                viewrecords: true,
                sortname: 'FileName',
                sortorder: "desc"
            });
            //jQuery("#" + subgrid_table_id).jqGrid('navGrid', "#" + pager_id, { edit: false, add: false, del: false })
            
        }
    });


        $('#tblJQGrid').jqGrid('navGrid', '#jQGridDemoPager',
                 {
                     edit: true,
                     add: true,
                     del: true,
                     search: true,
                     searchtext: "Search",
                     addtext: "Add",
                     edittext: "Edit",
                     deltext: "Delete"
                 },
                 {   //EDIT
                     //                       height: 300,
                     //                       width: 400,
                     //                       top: 50,
                     //                       left: 100,
                     //                       dataheight: 280,
                     closeOnEscape: true,//Closes the popup on pressing escape key
                     reloadAfterSubmit: true,
                     drag: true,
                     afterSubmit: function (response, postdata) {
                         if (response.responseText == "") {

                             $(this).jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'json' }).trigger('reloadGrid');//Reloads the grid after edit
                             return [true, '']
                         }
                         else {
                             $(this).jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'json' }).trigger('reloadGrid'); //Reloads the grid after edit
                             return [false, response.responseText]//Captures and displays the response text on th Edit window
                         }
                     },
                     editData: {
                         EmpId: function () {
                             var sel_id = $('#jQGridDemo').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
                             var value = $('#jQGridDemo').jqGrid('getCell', sel_id, '_id');
                             return value;
                         }
                     }
                 },
                 {
                     closeAfterAdd: true,//Closes the add window after add
                     afterSubmit: function (response, postdata) {
                         if (response.responseText == "") {

                             $(this).jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'json' }).trigger('reloadGrid')//Reloads the grid after Add
                             return [true, '']
                         }
                         else {
                             $(this).jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'json' }).trigger('reloadGrid')//Reloads the grid after Add
                             return [false, response.responseText]
                         }
                     }
                 },
                 {   //DELETE
                     closeOnEscape: true,
                     closeAfterDelete: true,
                     reloadAfterSubmit: true,
                     closeOnEscape: true,
                     drag: true,
                     afterSubmit: function (response, postdata) {
                         if (response.responseText == "") {

                             $("#jQGridDemo").trigger("reloadGrid", [{ current: true }]);
                             return [false, response.responseText]
                         }
                         else {
                             $(this).jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'json' }).trigger('reloadGrid')
                             return [true, response.responseText]
                         }
                     },
                     delData: {
                         EmpId: function () {
                             var sel_id = $('#jQGridDemo').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
                             var value = $('#jQGridDemo').jqGrid('getCell', sel_id, '_id');
                             return value;
                         }
                     }
                 },
                 {//SEARCH
                     closeOnEscape: true

                 }
          );


    });
```

SubGrid url return this json :

```
[{"Id":0,"FileName":"91606246.pdf","Size":0.03}]
```

But the subgrid does not show received data. This is the snippet sc:
[Grid with subgrid empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnY0W.png)

I have the following configuration:

- MVC 4,
- net framework 4.5
- jquery-2.2.3.js
- jquery.jqGrid.min.js (@license Guriddo jqGrid JS - v5.1.1 ...)

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `dataType: 'json'` option in subgrid instead of `datatype: 'json'`. It could be your main problem.

I would strictly recommend you to add `idPrefix` option to subgrid, with some unique value like `idPrefix`. Fore example `idPrefix: "s_" + row_id + "_"` or `idPrefix: subgrid_id` or just `idPrefix: $.jgrid.randId()`. It will prevent you from later problems with id duplicates. The option `autoencode: true` is helpful too for the subgrid in many scenarios.

I recommend you to consider to use [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) (which I develop) instead of commercial Guriddo jqGrid JS. If you do prefer to use Guriddo, then you should think about the required payments (see [the prices](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334)) and about the holding of the license agreement.